# Naming high productivity group and low productivity group

Tags: word-choice

I am working on a paper that compares two group of people doing the same task. People in group 1 have high productivity while people in group 2 have low productivity. Now, I would like to find a name for each group so that the paper would be easier to read. I thought about: winner vs. loser or elite vs. public, but I feel they are inappropriate for some reasons. Could you please give me some suggestions?

**Updates**:

1. Actually, the subjects are working on software vulnerability discovery. And we can count the number of vulnerabilities discovered by each person. Then, we set a threshold t, and those who found more than t vulnerabilities will be put in the high productivity group and the rest will be put into the low productivity group.
2. The high productivity group size is much smaller than that of the low productivity group, which is a common phenomenon in many situations (sometime called 20/80 effect). So I am also hoping to reflect this size difference in their names...

Comment: High performers vs. low performers, perhaps. Could be abbreviated to HP vs. LP. (0:

Comment: As a language question I think what you have in the title is OK, or maybe "high productivity team" vs. "low productivity team". But this implies that the people alone are the reason. If that is not the case, but instead a process issue or quality issue, etc., different terms would be appropriate. More context is needed.

Comment: I've seen that when such a contrast being discussed in the context of business and finance, the words *leaders* and *laggards* usually come up.

Comment: Maybe *baseline group* and *superachievers*/*superachieving group*

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the context given, I'd have "security researchers" and "senior security researchers", and pay the latter group more

Comment: Thanks. Actually it is hard to say that members in the high productivity group are all senior and members in the low group are all junior, because they all contribute voluntarily. Therefore, one person in the low group could be a very senior researcher, but she just don't want to contribute.